# connect mysql database using flask

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-python, mysql-connector, flask-mysql

i am trying to connect the database mysql using flask-python . i  create a 'users' name table have two columns 'fname' 'lname' datatype string in my database name 'login'

code

```
  from flask import Flask
  from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  app=Flask(__name__)
  app.config['MYSQL_HOST']='localhost'
  app.config['MYSQL_PORT']='3306'
  app.config['MYSQL_USER']='root'
  app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD']='12345'
  app.config['MYSQL_DB']='login'
  mysql=MySQL(app)
  @app.route('/insert')
  def insert():
   fname="arslan" 
   lname="arshad"
   cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execution("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname) VALUES(%s,%s)",(fname,lname))
   mysql.connection.commit()
   cur.close()
   return "inserted"
  app.run(debug=True)
```

ERROR:

TypeError
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You are passing the port as a string. Does it happen to actually need be an integer?

Answer (score 1):

I find my Error, i was using string value ..

```
  app.config['MYSQL_PORT']='3306' ##wrong
  app.config['MYSQL_PORT']=3306 ##correct
```

function accept a integer value so error show
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer